# Search scope shows Empty - Add rules

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-scope

I've created a new search scope and set up a rule for it but I think there's still something I need to do to activate it since in update status it's showing 'Empty - Add rules'.

[image]
What am I missing to get the update status to 'ready'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include all content as a rule by default, your exclusion then works with this to make the list.

Comment: Amazing, I'd never have thought of that!  I can stop smashing my head into the desk now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be excluding all the sites from the http://totaljobsgroup.com domain and I think you only want to exclude the site collection called technology ?
if so then when adding a new rule select Folder from web address instead of domain.

Hope this helps

Renzo

Answer (score 0):

A timer job will run (typically every 15 minutes) and build the scopes.